# Not return parent using filter in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to filter some div based on text. so I am using .filter method. I want filter to return .parent() but it is only returning it child. I found fix for this but I want to know why it is not returning parent(). [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pxeV/)

```
$(function(){
var check= $('.sub').filter(function(){
if($(this).text()=='remove')
return $(this).parent();
})
console.log(check)
})

<div class="main">
<div class="sub">remove</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
<div class="sub">remove</div>
</div>
```

Comment: filter is used to filter a list of matched elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
var check = $('.sub').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() == 'remove';
}).parent();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2pxeV/1/)